# How to remove zero vectors from a list of list in r

Tags: r

### Problem:

I have a list of two lists of three vectors. I would like to remove the zero vector from each sublist.

### Example:

```
x <- list(x1=c(0,0,0), x2=c(3,4,5), x3=c(45,34,23))
y <- list(y1=c(2,33,4), y2=c(0,0,0), y3=c(4,5,44))
z <- list(x, y)
```

### Try:

I tried this:

```
res <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {lapply(1:3, function(j) z[[i]][[j]][z[[i]][[j]] != 0])})
```

Which gave me this:

```
> res
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
numeric(0)

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 45 34 23


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  2 33  4

[[2]][[2]]
numeric(0)

[[2]][[3]]
[1]  4  5 44
```

### Problem with the output:

I do not want `numeric(0)`.

### Expected output:

```
x= list(x2, x3)
y=list(y1, y3)
```

Any idea, please?

Comment: `lapply` (etc) will always give you output that has the same length as the input: each element is transformed; nothing else is done. What you want isn’t a mapping (which is what `lapply` performs) but a modification of the length of of the list. This can be done e.g. via the `Filter` function (capital `F`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you so much. I understand it now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your structure of list of lists I would go with the following:

```
filteredList <- lapply(z, function(i) Filter(function(x) any(x != 0), i))

x <- filteredList[[1]]
y <- filteredList[[2]]

x
##$`x2`
##[1] 3 4 5

##$x3
##[1] 45 34 23
y
##$`y1`
##[1]  2 33  4

##$y3
##[1]  4  5 44
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try a `tidyverse` if the nested list structure is not important

```
library(tidyverse)
z %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  keep(~all(. != 0))
$x2
[1] 3 4 5

$x3
[1] 45 34 23

$y1
[1]  2 33  4

$y3
[1]  4  5 44
```

Answer (score 0):

define z as

```
z <- c(x, y)
# z <- unlist(z, recursive = F)  if you cannot define z by yourself.
```

then use:

```
z[sapply(z, any)]

#$`x2`
#[1] 3 4 5

#$x3
#[1] 45 34 23

#$y1
#[1]  2 33  4

#$y3
#[1]  4  5 44
```

---

Please note:

As in the tradition of lang `C`. Every integer/ numeric != 0 will be casted to `TRUE`. So in this task we can use this logic. `?any` will eval FALSE if all values are `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you please explain further what does `all` means and why I need to use it in this way. This will help me to understand what I am doing and I will really learn a new thing. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I tried your answer but it gave me this: `Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical`

Comment: Is `all` really what OP wants? Not `any`? Anyway, I appreciate the cleverness but I think it’s potentially too clever since it relies heavily on implicit type conversions. The warnings are a good indication that this shouldn’t be done. I’d rather use something a tad more explicit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I corrected my answer independently from your comment. It needs to be `any`!

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
x <- list(x1=c(0,0,0), x2=c(3,4,5), x3=c(45,34,23))
y <- list(y1=c(2,33,4), y2=c(0,0,0), y3=c(4,5,44))
z <- list(x, y)

lapply(z, function(a) a[unlist(lapply(a, function(b) !identical(b, rep(0,3))))])

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$`x2`
#[1] 3 4 5
#
#[[1]]$x3
#[1] 45 34 23
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$`y1`
#[1]  2 33  4
#
#[[2]]$y3
#[1]  4  5 44
```

Answer (score 0):

with `purrr` it can be really compact

```
library(purrr)
map(z, keep ,~all(.!=0))
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$x2
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# [[1]]$x3
# [1] 45 34 23
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$y1
# [1]  2 33  4
# 
# [[2]]$y3
# [1]  4  5 44
```

If it wasn't for the annoying warnings we could do just `map(z, keep , all)`